# send HTML content in post request using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post

I need to send a div element's inner HTML to server through post request.

What I tired using javascript is,
Created a hidden input element and tried to assign the div's inner HTML in it and submitted it to the server. Since the inner HTML has single, double quotes it is not properly assigned to the value of input element.

Kindly suggest best solutions.

Comment: try to store in `textarea`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `urlencode(str)` and `urldecode(str)` function or you can refer

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FencodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FdecodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)